# angular 5 directive that tracks window scrollbar

Tags: angular

I want to create a directive that listens to window scroll, and fires an event whenever the top or bottom of the page is approached. I want any DOM element to be able to respond to these events, in case it is interested. I can write such a directive with `@HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event"])`, but on which DOM element should I put it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the window's current scroll offset in this way. In my example, I simply set a boolean after scrolling at least 150px.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const scroll$ = fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(
    throttleTime(10),
    map(() => window.pageYOffset),
  );

  scroll$.subscribe((value) => this.contentScrolled = (value > 150));
}
```

You could subscribe to this window event in your directive.

Comment: but that's not what I asked, my question was where to place the directive